# Assigning unlisted shortcut keys / key binding

Tags: aptana

As one of the millions of people around the world I do not have an "anglo-saxon" keyboard and frustratingly I don't have {} on my keyboard (i have è ° à and other useful stuff for italian). How hassly for programming is that!!!!!

So I'd like to assign a key binding to curly brackets but they are not listed in the preferences->general->keys.

Is it possible? Have I missed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm, you'd like to press one key and instead get a curly brace? You could so that using commands. The example below approximates what the editor would normally do by inserting a {} and placing the cursor in the middle.

1) Create a new Ruble via File > New Ruby project > Go to next page for "templates" and select a Ruble template

2) Edit the commands/commands.rb file and insert the following (adjusting as appropriate)

```
require 'ruble'

command 'Insert Right Brace' do |cmd|
  cmd.key_binding = 'q' # change this for a new key binding
  cmd.scope = 'source'
  cmd.output = :insert_as_snippet
  cmd.input = :selection
  cmd.invoke do |context|
    print '{${0}}' # snippet to surround the cursor with braces
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way that isn't project reliant? I just want a short cut that allows me to assign lets say ctrl + è (for example) to give me a left curly bracket.   Then it doesn't matter if I'm just editing a html file or a php file or if I'm opening up a new project...

Comment: This will work across all file types in all projects. You're only creating a project to hold the code that does the key binding.